# How can I POST a file using ServiceStack IRestGateway

Tags: servicestack

I'm currently accessing a 3rd party restAPI using ServiceStacks IRestGateway with my own backing class. It's basically the same as the ServiceStack.Stripe [gateway](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Stripe/blob/master/src/Stripe/StripeGateway.cs).

My issue is that I'm not sure how to handle File uploads. I know using one of the service clients you can easily do file [uploads](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#file-uploads). Is there a way to re-use this existing implementation without switching to a service client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IRestGateway](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/IRestGateway.cs) does not include any APIs for HTTP File Uploads. If you need to a send a file with those restricted APIs you'd need a DTO to include a `byte[]` property to capture the File contents as well as basic metadata like the file name, file/content type, etc.

An alternative to uploading files with ServiceStack's [C#/.NET Service Clients](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client) is to use the [HTTP Util extension methods](https://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils#uploading-files) which provides simple APIs to upload files via `FileInfo` for `Stream`.

Comment: Would you suggest sticking with IRestGateway? I like that it's very easy to Mock and is very basic and simple. Does what I need other that the file stuff. 

I'll look into the extension methods and creating the appropriate DTO.

Comment: @tracstarr that's really up to you, you could also have a superset interface that inherits IRestGateway and adds any additional generic methods that you need.